# print next line only if it begins with a specific word

Tags: python

I am a bit new to python and I was wondering if anyone can help. Basically I am reading contents of a file and when I find the word "prb" I want to check the next line using the next() function and if it starts with the word "rt", i want to print both lines. So far I wrote this piece of code:

```
    with open('/home/user/Desktop/3rdstep.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.readline()
    for line in f:
            if "prb" in line:
                    try:
                            myword = next(f)
                            if "rt" in myword:
                                    print(line.strip())
                                    print(myword)
                    except:
                            print("pass")
```

This works fine but the only problem is that it skips randomly "rt" words for a reason I don't know. Can anyone help please or have someone done something similar?

Thanks

Comment: can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input has two consecutive lines starting with `'prb'` followed by line starting with `'rt'` then they are skipped. The only exception is the case where they are the first three lines in the file. This is because `for line in f:` reads the first line starting with `'prb'` and `myword = next(f)` reads the second line. Thus on the following iteration `line` starts with `'rt'`.

Instead of reading the next line you could store the previous line and then check if two lines match:

```
prev = ''
with open('/home/user/Desktop/3rdstep.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if prev.startswith('prb') and line.startswith('rt'):
            print(prev.strip())
            print(line)
        prev = line
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `if myword.startswith("rt"):` instead of `if "rt" in myword:`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, however this outputs the same result as before and does not solve my problem.